# ElasticSearch conditional 'should' based on document properties

Tags: elasticsearch

What's the best way to write an ElasticSearch query with a should clause where the values in the should clause are different depending on some other property of the document?

Here's the use case: In this application, end users search for products that are available from multiple shippers.

Based on some business rules, the application populates the `should` clause with the IDs of shippers that can fulfill the order.  The query returns appropriate search results based on the `shipper_id` values in the should.

Now, we need to specify a second list of `shipper_id` values based on some properties of the document.  If the document has a property `"color": "red"`, use the current business logic and the same `should` with the same list of shipper_ids.
But for documents that have a non-red value for `color`, there will be a different list of shipper_ids.

We want to return both sets of documents in the search results.  Each document returned must either be (1) red color and using the existing business logic and list of shipper_ids, or (2) non-red color and using a different list of shipper_ids.

This is what the query looks like now, without the new requirements:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "product_status": {
                            "query": "active"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "shipper_id": "39"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "shipper_id": "40"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "shipper_id": "41"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "shipper_id": "48"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "shipper_id": "49"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "shipper_id": "50"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": [],
            "should": [],
            "must_not": []
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "last_modified": "DESC"
        }
    ],
    "from": 0,
    "size": 50
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way is to have 2 `must` in the `should` query.

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {}
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {}
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

[image]